# Dijit Tree disable item

Tags: javascript, dojo

I try to disable (not click) item (icon+label) of dijit tree, but I don't find a solution. I try: jQuery attr, domAttr and domClass, but no result. How can I it? 
Thanks

Comment: I have tried:                                                         1- jQuery('#<id div>').attr("disabled", true)                           2- domAttr.set(<widget id>, "disabled", true)                                               domClass.add(<widget id>, "disabled")

Comment: No, you need to try `.attr("disabled", "disabled");` and `.prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: Did it work? please reply. If it does, I will post it as an answer and you can accept it?